# PostgreSQL: How to create index on very large table without timeouts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to add a simple index with the following SQL in Postgres, but the command keeps timing out:

```sql
CREATE INDEX playlist_tracklinks_playlist_enid ON playlist_tracklinks (playlist_enid);
```

The table definition is as follows:

```
=> \d playlist_tracklinks
         Table "public.playlist_tracklinks"
     Column     |     Type      |     Modifiers
----------------+---------------+--------------------
 playlist_enid  | numeric(20,0) | not null default 0
 tracklink_enid | numeric(20,0) | not null default 0
 position       | integer       | not null default 1
```

There are around 2.2 billion rows in the table, and it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
```

I tried increasing the query timeout time with the following:

```sql
SET statement_timeout TO 360000000;
```

However it still hits that threshold.  I have tried with and without `CONCURRENTLY`, and am sort of at a loss for what to do.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error is not caused by `statement_timeout`, but by a user cancel request. What interface do you use to access PostgreSQL? Try setting the `s_t` value to `0`, which turns this off.

Comment: I'm using psql to access the server remotely (this is Heroku's Postgres offering, so I don't have direct server access).

Comment: I'll try creating the index with `statement_timeout` set at `0`

Comment: I tried with statment_timeout set to 0, and it still failed...  I'm not really sure why...

Comment: Looks like Heroku is killing your connection, check with their support if the really do that. Also, try increasing `maintenance_work_mem` to the higher value you can, this will improve the index creating.

Comment: It was Heroku killing connections (the server ran out of temporary space).  I did increase `maintenance_work_mem` as well - thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Heroku killing connections (the server ran out of temporary space).  Contacting Heroku support was the solution eventually...

Answer (score 1):

You could try indexing a part-piece of the table, say the first 10k rows using the `WHERE` statement. Then you might be able to see if that works and how long it takes. Reference for using `WHERE` with `CREATE INDEX` here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html

Is it possible your column contains non-unique numbers? That could potentially cause an issue (I'm not sure if an index requires unique values on a column in this case).

Comment: It definitely does have non-unique numbers - I want to create a simple index vs a unique index.  I don't think it requires unique values with this syntax (it worked on smaller tables).

Comment: @JacobWG Thanks for clearing that up. Perhaps try the partial index?

Comment: after I create the partial index, then what?  Do I create multiple partial indexes?  Can I combine them into one?

Comment: Because your data contains non-unique numbers, it usually indicates a common value (perhaps the default of 0?) which will not need indexing if 90% of the values are 0. Therefore your partial index could cover values greater than 0. More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Yeah, they all need indexing...  :/  This is a join table between two other tables, so each field refers to a primary key of another table.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic with `numerics` is very slow. This includes the comparisons needed to build and use the indexes. I suggest that you change the `enid` types to `char(20)` or just `varchar` if you do not do any arithmetic (other than comparisons) on them, and perhaps `bigint` if you do. Bigint isn't quite enough for the largest possible 20-digit number—I don't know what sort of information this ids carry around, if they can really be that big.